# can i install a package locally and globally at same time in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

I am working on a project. I have worked with `nodemon` that is installed globally for development.

I edited my `package.json` file to add a script to automatically run a nodemon script - as shown below:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "dev": "nodemon  -e js,pug"
}
```

Now when another developer runs:

`npm start dev`

they will surely get a error if they have not installed the `nodemon` module.

I know that the solution is to install `nodemon` locally as a development dependency.

Is it possible to work around this problem without installing it locally?

Can I install nodemon both locally and globally at the same time?

Comment: If you are installing it globally then why do you need it to install locally????

Comment: because i want other developers to also use my code without any problem but in the same type i want it globally installed

Comment: So the other users can also download it globally and use

Answer (score 1):

simply install it globally and you can use it in any of your project

command :

`npm i -g nodemon`

now you don't need to install it locally at all to make it work on your project.